# Use a Mosfet/PNP transistor to boost voltage for mcu pin

Tags: mosfet, esp8266

I am looking to turn off/on a 5v laser diode with an esp8266 micro controller. 
The mcu's gpio pins can only take 3.3v. 
A PNP, NPN and mosfet, among these three which will help me boost the voltage to 5v and how should it be connected?

Comment: Do you have 5V available?

Comment: yes. i have 5v pin on the mcu.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f940pn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When selecting the MOSFET, make sure it is a 'logic level' MOSFET that can turn on fully with 3.3V gate to source, and handle the current the laser diode uses.

Note that I don't show any current limiting here.  If the laser diode doesn't include that you will need to use a resistor in series.